# Custom Chain only allow one account to submit smart contracts

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Can you lock down a distributed custom chain where only one user account can submit smart contracts? I don't want anyone filling my chain with data unrelated to my dApp

Comment: Is it your private chain? If it is your private chain you can control to prefunded accounts or mining nodes with mine accounts. Account with emty balance cannot send transaction to block. Additional check security nodes of private chain - firewall constraints, nodiscover constrain in cmd geth running string.

Comment: I had thought about that but we wanted to give people the ability to mine.  I'm not sure I understand the last part, geth running string?